# android app title naming

Tags: android, title, non-latin

I'm trying to upload my android app, but instead of my app name "Соновник" it shows question marks. I've stored all my string in the `values/strings.xml` file. Is there some naming convention or am I supposed to do something for my app title to support UTF characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be a problem with your browser (or google's side) that it is not showing title correctly, otherwise on device i believe it should be fine.